# Please explain this forcing string comparison code

Tags: javascript

How do I read `String comparison can be forced by: "" + a == "" + b` from https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.6?

1. I don't know the correct order of evaluating this (left-right or inside-outside)
2. What are the intermediate conversions and values that lead to the final result?
3. What are the concepts involved in those intermediate conversions, and are there other methods (less shorthand ways like `Number()` instead of `unary +`) to implement those conversions to make it more readable to a beginner?
4. When is such a pattern used (why force string comparison, why force it this way assuming there are other ways) and are there pitfalls?

Comment: I coerce numbers because I'm lazy and prefer terseness over readability (I'm retired).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDN has a [table of operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table).

Addition (string and arithmetic) happens before equality. All else being equal, things are done left to right.

So given:

```
"" + a == "" + b
```

first `"" + a` is evaluated and is equivalent to `String(a)`.

Then `"" + b` is evaluated and is equivalent to `String(b)`.

The two results are then compared using `==`.

It's used because it's less to write than `String(a)`.

Whether `Number(a)` is more readable than `+a` is moot. There are things to learn about both. For conversion to number there is also *parseInt*, *parseFloat* and multiplication by 1, so all the following:

```
parseInt(a) 
parseFloat(a) 
+a
a * 1
```

*might* all give the same result (e.g. where *a* is an integer string like 10). But *might* not for other values (like '10.6'). Conversion to number is also complicated by NaN, so if either or both expressions resolve to NaN, then they don't equal each other ('cos NaN isn't `==` or `===` to any value, even itself).

Have fun. :-)

Comment: Perfectly clear now. I was overthinking, grappling with what does `" + a == "` mean initially, and why it was wrapped in another layer of double quotes. Should have simply interpreted it left to right.